# Tomcat server is responding with 400 bad request for this URL

Tags: tomcat, configuration, bad-request

I've deployed a static web application using Apache Tomcat 8.5.8

When I call the normal URL, it works fine.
http://localhost/example/index.html

But when I call the following URL, it gives me 400 bad request error.
http://localhost/example/index.html?host_info=Outlook|Web

I know it's because the URL has the special character (|).
But I couldn't configure the Tomcat, because I am pretty new with the Tomcat configuration.

And I can't change the URL, because it's not something I generate. It is from the other component.

So I really need to configure the Tomcat server so that it can accept the url.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the tomcat 8.0.* instead of 8.5
I also faced the same issue before, and I had to downgrade the tomcat to 8.0.28

Comment: Downgrading the tomcat version is not a solution. It will increase the threats to security of an application.

Comment: Please don't downgrade Tomcat. This presents huge security loophole.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior was introduced in Tomcat 7.0.76, 8.0.42 and 8.5.12, to conform `RFC 7231`.

This enforced check can be revert using the property `requestTargetAllow` in `catalina.properties` to allow forbiden characters:

`tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}`

Comment: your post is not accurate it's Tomcat 7.0.73 https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60594