# Apache Tomcat drops connection with 400 error and no explanation with certain URLs

Tags: tomcat, urlencode, http-status-code-400

I have an application that uses Javascript code to generate URLs that are sent to a REST endpoint running under Apache Tomcat 8.5.  The data sent to the URL includes an identifier field that may contain "special" characters.  I encode this identifier using the Javascript function `encodeURIComponent`.

However, with some of the identifier strings, the connection is being instantly terminated after the URL is sent (without even waiting for the request to be fully sent), with the error `400 Bad Request` and an empty response entity.

An example URL that causes the failure is:

```
 http://localhost:3000/admin_api/getTranscript/%2B~%2B)%2Fe*3%3Ep%2596%5B(%2Fv%3C03
```

This doesn't appear to be related to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218574/tomcat-server-is-responding-with-400-bad-request-for-this-url) because the characters causing issue in that particular case are `|`, `{` and `}`, none of which are present in my URL.

Why is Tomcat rejecting this URL, and what can I do to prevent this issue?  I'd prefer a change on the server side rather than client, because I have already-deployed clients that would need updating.

Comment: Unless I am much mistaken, `(` and `)` are not legal components of a URL, so there is something wrong with your encoding process.

Comment: @EJP - I'm using the standard javascript `encodeURIComponent` function, which is explicitly designed for this purpose. It seems to me that `(` and `)` *are* valid URL characters -- they're defined in RFC3986 as part of the `sub-delims` set.  The path component of a URL is then defined as `path = path-abempty / [others]`, `path-abempty = *( "/" segment )`, `segment = *pchar`, and finally `pchar = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"`, so I don't see a problem with the URL here.

Comment: Ah -- found another question & answer that does seem to match my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220740/why-is-this-url-returning-error-400-from-tomcat